# WCF return entity framework classes that have WCF atrributes on them

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf

I recently talked to a programmer who has never used the entity framework, however used WCF services often. So I decided to create some models using the entity framework code first approach. I thought I added the proper attributes to the classes so that data can be returned and so on. However, when testing the service in visual studio I get this exception.

--Update--
Inside of the classes removing the virtual keyword makes everything work. However in my returned classes a quiz no longer has any values inside of the terms property.

--Update--
Found a way that isn't what I really want but it works. Created two new classes, DB_Quiz, DB_Term, they're identical to the entity framework classes aside from virtual keywords. 
Then during the method call I do something like this.

```
var query = (from search in db.Quizes select new DB_Quiz() {
                ID =search.ID, Title = search.Title

            });

            var obj = query.FirstOrDefault();


            var termQuery = (from search in db.Terms where search.Quiz.ID == obj.ID select new DB_Term() {
                ID = search.ID, Phrase = search.Phrase, Definition = search.Definition
            }).ToList();

            obj.Terms = termQuery;
```

--Update-- 
Found a good solution however relating to this question it does not answer it correctly. Same as update above however the linq query is slightly more advanced.

```
var query = (from search in db.Quizes
                         select new DB_Quiz()
                         {
                             ID = search.ID,
                             Title = search.Title,
                             Terms =
                             (from inner in search.Terms select new DB_Term() {
                                 ID = inner.ID, Phrase = inner.Phrase, Definition = inner.Phrase
                             }).ToList()
                         });

            return query.ToList();
```

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:61149/DataWorker.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

I just want to build my backend to use the entity framework because of what I have seen it makes working with databases so easy. Someone please help me understand this problem. I would really like to stick to WCF services because I am using the UWP as my client application. From what I have seen the entity framework doesn't work well with WCF services.

My classes:
ContextClass -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web;

namespace QuizletBackend.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class QuizContext : DbContext
    {
        public QuizContext() : base("name=LocalServer")
        {

        }

        [DataMember]
        public DbSet<Quiz> Quizes { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DbSet<Term> Terms { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Quiz class -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web;

namespace QuizletBackend.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Quiz
    {
        [Key]
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Title cannot exceed 150 characteres.")]
        public String Title { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual List<Term> Terms { get; set; } = new List<Term>();
    }
}
```

Term class -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web;

namespace QuizletBackend.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Term
    {
        [DataMember]
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String Phrase { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String Definition { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual Quiz Quiz { get; set; }
    }
}

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IDataWorker.DoWork()
   at DataWorkerClient.DoWork()

Inner Exception:
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

Inner Exception:
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)

Inner Exception:
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use data contract classes as your entity classes. I would like to recommend you to use two different entity classes. Reason is if you want to change the data contract you can do it easily without effecting your  entity framework classes. Also this will give you more control over both EF and WCF.

Comment: Can you provide something a little more in depth regarding use two different entity classes. I am new to the entity framework and also new to using data contracts with wcf.

Comment: Can you please put some code Where this exception coming. looks like a problem with your connection to DB

Comment: Literally this code. And then inside of a svc I just do a simple query to return one quiz from the db. I can pause in the debugger before it returns that object. The object in the debugger is correct. After returning the object this error occurs.

Comment: @Seminda I kind of understand what you're saying with the whole two different classes. However can you provide an example in code. As an answer. The code doesn't have to be 100% correct and compile friendly however I need to see what you mean by two different classes.

Comment: I will do it for you. I have few suggestions. I will add then in my answer.

Comment: One way that I understand your solution is I have created a DB_Quiz and DB_Term with the same attributes. During the linq query I end it with select new DB_Quiz{} within that new select statement I can get the quiz to return correctly however populating the terms list correctly I have no idea.

Comment: Never ever use your entities as DTOs. This is grossly negligent. WCF will serialize them and gets the complete object graph from the DB. This will result in n+1 and spams your database with unnecessary queries, Use DTOs to transfer you Data. You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) for this.

Comment: I figured that using the entity object would result in a lot of queries being executed. I am new to the entity framework and I am also slightly new to wcf and data being sent over a network. I figured that something as beautiful as the automatic generation of classes for me with entity would be too good to be true. So after my classes today I am going to look into something like AutoMapper. Before then would you be able to post some code or something along those lines showing the use of AutoMapper in an example with context to my question?

Comment: @BaileyMiller this would be to much for one Answer. But there are many Tutorials outside that will teach how to use EF, AutoMapper and WCF. If you have any particular questions or problems, search SO or ask it as a new question. As a small hint, AutoMapper has a great method called `ProjectTo` that made it a breeze to project you data to a DTO and use this in WCF.